# How to run a specific fastlane task, like 'pilot' only

Tags: react-native, fastlane

When I run `fastlane beta`, it compiles the whole project and then uploads to testflight. The compiling phase is very time-consuming.

How to run the uploading phase (I guess it's `pilot`) only, when I don't need to compile but just to upload to testflight when the previous uploading fails?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `Fastfile` in `/fastlane`. It should have a `beta` lane with some commands. You can change those as you want, and e.g. remove the "build" step (or do so in a copy of the `beta` lane). Of course you then have to supply the path of the app to be uploaded via `pilot` - see https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/#parameters for a list of parameters (`ipa` in this case probably).